# Magento: utilizar múltiplas lojas com uma unica instancia

Tags: magento, amazon-aws

Penso em montar em uma instancia EC2/AWS algumas lojas utilizando o Magento.
Dúvida: seria possível criar lojas distintas, com usuários, clientes e demais dados separados uma da outra, ou seja, ter um núcleo único e instancias desta configuração?

Answer (score 1):

A instância é sua para operar como desejar, então é possível sim por exemplo executar várias copias do Magento na mesma instância. Entretanto, isso pode tornar mais difícil de gerenciar e escalar as lojas individualmente.